# svcutil and specified fields

Tags: c#, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I am generating a datacontract with svcutil from a webservice.

```
svcutil /language:cs /noConfig /targetclientversion:Version35 
        /out:Generated\ProductService.cs http://example.com/ProductService.svc?wsdl
```

The fields generated looks like this:

```
private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> createdField;
private bool createdFieldSpecified;
```

How can the fields be both nullable and have a specified field?

Comment: Does the property expose itself as `DateTime` or `DateTime?` ?

Comment: It is exposed as System.Nullable<DateTime>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it depends on the source Wsdl. I bet there is something this (not sure of the syntax):

```
<xsd:element name="created" type="xsd:datetime" minOccurs="0" xsd:nil="true" />
```

`svcutil.exe` use `nillable` to produce a `Nullable<>` field, and `minOccurs` to produce a field + specified combination.

I also bet the WSDL is not a .Net generated WSDL !

Comment: That is exactly how it looks. Now I understand. Thanks. You are wrong on .Net. Some other things in the wsdl shows that it is definitely a .Net service

Answer (score 1):

The class generation is driven by XSD schema of the web service.

In order to generate nullable fields. The field should be marked as `nillable`.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="created" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="true" />
```

The XML will look like this.

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <created xsi:nil="true" />
</root>
```

I believe that this field in your schema looks like this:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="created" />
```

and it would omit the element completely if `createdFieldSpecified = false`:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</root>
```

The bottom line: web service schema should be updated in order to generate nullable fields with `svcutil`.